# Do Consequences change their severity if renamed?

Tags: fate-core, consequences

As per title. My character has **Broken wrist** moderate consequence and after appropriate time and a successful roll to heal wants to rename that to **Forearm in splints**. Would the consequence become mild after it is renamed?

It seems to make sense that if healing has started, the consequence is not as problematic as when I got it. Also, it seems to be easier to care about an arm in a cast than a floppy one. Also, I've heard that some groups require more than one roll to recover from moderate and severe consequences.

With the above in mind, if I my character has **Axe lodged in cranium** as severe consequence and succeeds at +6 roll to rename that to **Underwent neurosurgery**, would that renamed one occupy Moderate or still Severe consequence? Would I later have to rename that to **Bandaged head** and go through a total of 3 rolls to remove it completely? What difficulty would I roll against in each iteration?

Comment: If you rename "torture" to "enhanced interrogation" that makes everything better.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## NO

You do not free up the more severe consequence slot just because you start to recover. There is a time to wait once recovery has begun that is part of what makes it a **consequence**.

From the [SRD](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/conflicts) (emphasis mine):

> If you succeed at the recovery action, or someone else succeeds on a recovery action for you, you get to rename the consequence aspect to show that it’s in recovery. So, for example, Broken Leg could become Stuck in a Cast, Scandalized could become Damage Control, and so on. **This doesn’t free up the consequence slot**, but it serves as an indicator that you’re recovering, and it changes the ways the aspect’s going to be used while it remains.
>
> Whether you change the consequence’s name or not—and sometimes it might not make sense to do so—mark it with a star so that everyone remembers that recovery has started.
>
> Then, you just have to wait the time.